# Casting a ActiveRecord collection from one type to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, casting, find, unique

Let's assume I have two Rails *ActiveRecord* models, **CarType** (make/model of car) and **Car** (instance of a CarType).
Car *belongs_to* CarType, and CarType *has_many* Cars.

I want a list of Cars, but only with unique CarTypes (no duplicate CarTypes in the results).

Basically, I want the results of:

```
CarType.find(:all, :include => [:cars])
```

...but cast as a collection of Car objects instead. How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT**

I started solving this by executing the `CarType.find` statement above, reverse-engineering Rails' generated SQL code (Rails actually produces two SQL statements) and then using `Car.find_by_sql`, but I feel the solution becomes very bulky.

Comment: So you want to retrieve only one car per CarType?

Comment: Yes, correct: just one Car per CarType. Side question: would sort order affect which Car (since there can be multiple) would be selected for each CarType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, `Cars.group("cartype_id")` is what you are looking for. And answering your side question, afaik sorting is applied after the group by.

Comment: Almost! This solved it: `Car.find(:all, :include => [:car_type], :group => :car_type_id)`. Thank you @bassneck!

Comment: Interesting... I checked my code on my project and it worked. But anyway, glad you sorted it out. Cheers :)